# Windows 10 Pro long boot time with SSD - Need help assessing Boot Trace result

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

I'm currently experiencing around 2 minutes long of boot time on *Windows 10 Pro* with a 500GB Samsung 850 EVO SSD as a boot drive without Fast Startup.

---

I've done several measures like disabling some startup items, reducing timeout time during boot to 3 seconds, and making sure AHCI mode was on. 
I have tried collecting the boot trace but will need some help in recognizing the issue to solve.

Can someone point out what can I do to get the proper boot time for the SSD? Thanks in advance.

Boot trace archive link: https://we.tl/t-epK88eka8a

Comment: Is it any quicker when you use safe mode? Have you done a clone from an old HDD to the 850? Are you using the same login profile as you used before? What spec of the computer?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas My Safe Boot time clocked at 19 seconds; no, I didn't clone it from any old HDD, it was a fresh install, the low boot time was noticeable since the 1803 update, hence a different profile; i9-9900K with 32GB of RAM and ROG Z390-E motherboard. My hypothesis was that something from the update was the cause, but was considering to identify other problems from the trace before updating to 1903.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no specific app, driver or any service that takes time while tracing the boot sequence then try this trick (worked for me!) disable 'fast startup' then reboot your machine & enable 'fast startup' back again.

Comment: I have tried that before, it didn't work.

Comment: Using Fast Startup in itself doesn't affect the cold boot time, which is what I'm trying to improve here. I've disabled Fast Startup and Hibernate through the elevated command prompt since I won't be using it.

Comment: A 2GB file would be tedious to deal with, it would be a nice idea to have a software that can create an easy to understand report

Comment: Its 17.8GB after its unzipped!